# How can i config with docker to pulling images just from my private repository instead of docker.io?

Tags: docker

With version 1.10 I can do that by config block-repository docker.io , but this config deleted in 1.12 so I don't know how can i make docker agent just communicating with my private repository only :(

Comment: I don't think that's a supported config... you might be able to fudge it by only having the CA certificate for your private repo available then ssl to docker.io will fail

Comment: Are you just wanting to allow pulling from a private registry, or do you also want to restrict the ability to pull from the docker hub?

Comment: I want to restrict the ability to pull from the docker hub